# Magento after upgrading to 2.2 issue coming while editing product

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, magento2.2

I did upgrade Magento from **2.1.4 to 2.2.2**

I am getting issue while editing the product in back end.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type
>   in isset or empty in
>   /vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition/Data.php on line
>   126
>
> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or
>   empty in /vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition/Data.php
>   on line 126
>   /vendor/magento/module-ui/Config/Reader/Definition/Data.php(126):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Illegal offset ...',
>   '/var/www/html/u...', 126, Array)
>   /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(382):
>   Magento\Ui\Config\Reader\Definition\Data->get(Array)
>   /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(396):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
>   Array, false)
>   /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(396):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
>   Array, false)
>   /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(396):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
>   Array, false)
>   /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(305):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
>   ..........
>   ..........

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I migrated the data from `magento 1.9.3.7` to `magento 2.2.5` using the data migration tool. When I click the add/Edit product button through admin panel, it showed me the same error. The way I resolved it was to go to `Admin->Store->Attribute Set`. And edited the `Default` and `Migration_Default` Attributes Set. Initially the `Migration_Default` Attribute had the attribute sets but the Default was empty. I added the attributes to the Default Attribute Set and executed the reindex command

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Also make sure that the Schedule Design Update Group Contains the following attributes:

```
custom_design_from

custom_design_to

custom_design

custom_layout
```

And it worked for me...